# Visual Studio Xamarin on Windows 10: Cannot determine Java Version

Tags: java, visual-studio, xamarin

I've been trying to get started with Xamarin on Visual Studio Community 2019, but every time a new Android project is created and run, deployment is aborted and the warning below appears. I've already uninstalled and reinstalled both Java and VS, modified and repaired VS, and tried out different versions of the JDK, yielding no results. Any ideas on why this may be happening and how can it be fixed?

The current version of the JDK I'm using is 17.0.1
[image: Error message shown in Visual Studio]

Comment: Please don't image for showing your code and exceptions. just copy and pasted it. So, People can easily work on your code and exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can recheck if you have set up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android correctly.

Xamarin.Android uses the `Java Development Kit (JDK)` and the Android SDK to build apps. During installation, the Visual Studio installer places these tools in their default locations and configures the development environment with the appropriate path configuration.

And for most users these default locations will work without further changes.

Xamarin.Android uses [JDK 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download#openjdk-11), which is required for API 31 and greater, [JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8), which is required if you are developing for API level 24 to 30 (JDK 8 also supports API levels earlier than 24).

For example:

[image]

For most users these default locations will work without further changes.

For more, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/windows#configuration

For how to set up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android, you can check: [Setting up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows) .

**Note:**

I recommend that you remove the older sdk and jdk files and use the latest version of Visual Studio with the default JDK and SDK Settings.